# 301 Redirect entire site AND change permalinks

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect an entire site from the following structure:

http://www.example.com/01/01/2001/post

to

http://newsite.com/example/post

I found the following code, but was worried that it would point the redirect to the new site and include that date category in the permalink.  I have already migrated the site successfully without the date category showing on the new site.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.newdomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Will the above work, or will it point to a 404 because it redirects to the new site with the date category included, which doesn't exist?

Thanks for your thoughts on the best solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/([^/]+)/?$ http://newsite.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

#### Reference Doc: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)